# Can a from __future__ import ... guarantee Python 2 and 3 compatibility?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm not interested in warming up the "Python 2 or Python 3?" questions (even though [the most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5478518/321973) I found is over one year old), but I stumbled upon [this claim](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=3676):

> You can write the Python 3 code under Python 2 if your file begins
>   with the line:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import absolute_import, division, generators, unicode_literals, print_function, nested_scopes, with_statement
> ```
>
> With that line in place, your code will work with either Python 2 or
>   Python 3. There may be rare cases in which it doesn't work, but I have
>   not found any,

Is this true? Is this single line enough to make sure the code you write will run on both Python 2.x (>=2.5 I assume) and 3.x (assuming the modules imported are available in both)?

Comment: very related: [python _2or3 module?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5520286/321973)

Comment: You will need at least 2.6 for the important bits of that to work. With some fallbacks for renamed modules and functions, I think it's enough to get most simple Python 3 code working.

Comment: @ThomasK I'm currently using 2.7 anyway, is there a valid reason to still _use_ older versions for fresh code? (Support and maintenance are of course different issues)

Comment: Not really, no. If you're writing new code, it's unlikely that anyone on versions older than 2.6 will want to use it.

Comment: Worth reading: [Cheat Sheet: Writing Python 2-3 compatible code](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"It depends"

**No:** Adding these imports to your Python 2 code will not make it run under Python 3.

**Yes:** With these imports in place you can write code that runs under both Python 2 and Python 3.

**But**: Then again, you can do that without those imports as well, and several of them, such as `unicode_literals` have turned out to simply not be helpful. `generators` and `with_statement` have nothing to do with Python 2 to Python 3 at all, those are features added in versions of Python 2.

So in conclusion, these imports are a bit of a red herring, and the statement is more wrong than right.

**However,** that doesn't mean writing code that runs under both Python 2 and Python 3 is impossible, or even necessarily very hard. See http://python3porting.com/ for more info.

Comment: As a side-note, since 3.3 one can once again use `u"unicode"`

Comment: ```from __future__ import absolute_import, division, generators, unicode_literals, print_function, nested_scopes, with_statement; 
input("as @kindall below mentions, there are some things that these imports will not address.")```
I think the "Yes" part of the answer above is trivial; `print("hello world")` without any imports still runs under both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. This answer is correct, for more information, see http://python3porting.com/

Comment: This is a good answer, but I disagree that "several of them, such as `unicode_literals` have turned out to simply not be helpful" — the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` has been in my experience the most useful thing to do for converting from Python 2 to 3, and in fact fixing a lackadaisical approach to text versus binary data is the thing that for many people takes the most time when converting from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that no, this is baloney. Even with those imports, there are still significant differences between Python 2 and 3: for example, `input()` in Python 3 is like `raw_input()` in Python 2; `range()` in Python 3 is like `xrange()` in Python 2. In the case of `xrange()` you could probably get away with using `range()` in Python 2 as long as the ranges are small, but if they're large, your program could have very different memory usage under Python 2 and Python 3.

You could add something like this to your code:

```
try:
    range = xrange
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

But then you've got to find all those edge cases and fix them up. For example, there are the `keys()` and `values()` methods of `dict` that return iterators in Python 3 but lists in Python 2, so you'd need to write a `dict` subclass that "fixes" that (and then never use dictionary literals in your code without wrapping them, since those would otherwise be of the built-in `dict` type).

I suppose that, by using `__future__` and various fix-ups, and by limiting yourself to writing code in a subset of Python thus created that will run under both 2.x and 3.x, it might be possible to write code that runs in both versions. Seems like a lot of work, though. There's a reason there's a `2to3` utility...

Comment: Ah, I found [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5520286/321973) mentioning this as well. I guess I'll try to use Python 3.x directly.

Comment: Not that the 2to3 utility will guarantee it either. :-)

Comment: Side-note: the `future` package backports [`range`](http://python-future.org/reference.html#range) and `super()` among other things

Answer (score 5):

It's not impossible, depending on the demands of your codebase.  You will probably find the [six](http://packages.python.org/six/) (2 * 3, haha) library essential; another useful tool is [python-modernize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-modernize) which attempts to convert your code to a cross-compatible state.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to have a look at these

Answer (score 4):

It will make it more likely, but there are some things that cannot be gained from a `__future__` import, and some things that are removed going into 3.x.

Off the top of my head, you could still use parameter tuple unpacking, which is removed in 3.x, and you won't be able to use the nice tuple unpacking with the star operator that is introduced in 3.x.

E.g:

```
def some_function((x, y), magnitude): #This has been removed in 3.x
    pass

x, *y = (1, 2, 3) #This does not exist in 2.x
```

That said, with some care to avoid such things, you could definitely write code that works across both versions, yes.

Obviously, this also only applies to 2.x versions that have the features backported into them. Because of this, some of that line is actually completely pointless - for example, there is no reason to import `generators` as any version that can import the with statement will already have generators working as standard. Same goes for `nested_scopes`.

In general, I recommend just writing for 3.x - there are no barriers to having both versions installed and usable. If you really desperately need 2.x support, then write for 2.x with as many of the back-ported features as you want, and use 2to3 to clean up anything else.

Comment: On the last paragraph: Sometimes you are forced to 2.x by third party libraries (Storm, matplotlib, sympy and more). Also pypy isn't python 3 ready yet.

Comment: And that's why I included the *if you really desperately need 2.x support* - yes, sometimes there are libraries without replacements or support, and in that case, 2to3 in the future is the best answer.

Comment: Okay, I read that wrong (more like: If you have to code for an environment where only py2 is available. Okay, now that I type *that* I see that its equivalent and we agree).

Answer (score 3):

Nah. Others have pointed out some difference, there are others.  One of the most fundamental is that Python 3 native strings are multibyte - this raises issues when communicating with single-byte mechanisms, like pipes to other processes.  Others include the renaming of modules (Tkinter to tkinter), True and False are now keywords.

Even comparisons might not be the same, the following incorrect code:

```
num = 42
txt = "3"

if txt < num:
    print ('Wow!')
else:
    print ('Doh!')
```

produces a `TypeError` on Py3, but not on Py2.

Unpacking has been mentioned.  the dictionary methods `items()`, `keys()`, and `values()` return view objects (different method names are used on 2.7).  In Py3 iterators are used more, for example returned from `map()` and `filter()`, and so on....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *future* package: *pip install future*

```
In [1]: range(10)
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [2]: from future.builtins import range

In [3]: range(10)
Out[3]: range(0, 10)
```

Here is their cheat sheet with more examples: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

Comment: hey thanks, and great resource you link to. of course if one has to `pip install` something, the question is whether one might not simply install python 3 then...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I think it's partly so you can still use Python2-only libraries if you need to.

Comment: I just noticed `future` also provides a Py3ish `super()`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159479/321973). And I just re-discovered your link to python-future, no wonder it seemed familiar 