# How to fix: W602 deprecated form of raising exception

Tags: python, pylint, pep8

If I use pylint (via sublimerlinter) I get following warning message:

`W602 deprecated form of raising exception`

This I how I use exceptions in my code:

```
if CONDITION == True:
    raise ValueError, HELPING_EXPLANATION
```

Comment: I added this rather trivial Q&A because googling for `W602 deprecated form of raising exception` does not result in any helpful links.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Raise your exception like this:

```
if CONDITION == True:
    raise ValueError(HELPING_EXPLANATION)
```

From [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code - Programming Recommendations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id39):

> When raising an exception, use raise `ValueError('message')` instead of the older form `raise ValueError, 'message'`.
>
> The paren-using form is preferred because when the exception arguments are long or include string formatting, you don't need to use line continuation characters thanks to the containing parentheses. The older form will be removed in Python 3.

Comment: Similarly, if you want to add a traceback in Python 2.x, use `raise ValueError(HELPING_EXPLANATION), None, tb` instead of `raise ValueError, HELPING_EXPLANATION, tb` to avoid that warning.

Comment: For what its worth, there is no python3-forward-compatible way to add a traceback in Python 2.x.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - Great, thanks! I wish you posted that as an answer so I could upvote it and you could gain rep, but instead you'll have to settle for an upvote to your comment.

Comment: @JonasWielicki - Will 2to3 not handle either form?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare No idea. Maybe checking the [2to3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) will shed some light into this.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I considered it better to have that information directly below the valid answer. Anyway, concerning your question JonasWielicki [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25302886/321973) may be useful, especially the link in it

Comment: Looks like 2to3 will handle 2.x's `raise` syntax so long as the first arg isn't a tuple: "Converts raise E, V to raise E(V), and raise E, V, T to raise E(V).with_traceback(T). If E is a tuple, the translation will be incorrect because substituting tuples for exceptions has been removed in 3.0." (from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-raise))