# I'm getting an error when opening a Jupyter Notebook on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, relativedelta

I am getting the following error when trying to open a Jupyter Notebook in my Linux computer. It seems to be originating from the `relativedelta` type from the `dateutil` module.

```
raj@raj ~ $ jupyter-console 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raj/.local/bin/jupyter-console", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.app import main
  File "/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.consoleapp import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jupyter_client/consoleapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .session import Session
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 61, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, date_default
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jupyter_client/jsonutil.py", line 11, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
  File "/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._parser import parse, parser, parserinfo, ParserError
  File "/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .. import relativedelta
  File "/home/raj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.py", line 118
    raise TypeError, "relativedelta only diffs datetime/date"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: W602 deprecated form of raising exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991637/how-to-fix-w602-deprecated-form-of-raising-exception)

Comment: Have you used date somewhere? If yes then add the code where you have used date to your question.

Comment: No, I have never used.